# UIDatepicker set minimum minute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I need to display a date picker which allows selecting the only hour. at present, my approach is by setting maximum minute to zero so that minute selection won't enable. Perhaps this causes the date picker to select up to 11: 00 AM Now I am not able to select 12 PM and other hours in PM

Here is my code

```
_PICK_timeslot.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSIntegerMax fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setMinute:00];
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
[_PICK_timeslot setMaximumDate:date];
[_PICK_timeslot addTarget:self action:@selector(listen_datePicker) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: use `setMinimumDate` method with minimum minute value

Comment: @Rocky Like user should not have the option to select a minute. It should be set to zero

Comment: minimum minute method not available @Rocky

Comment: use `UIPickerView` as below answered.

Answer (score 0):

[UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) used for the inputting of date and time values, if You’ll need to input only hour value then you have to set up your own [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) containing the only hour range you’re looking for.